# How to solve ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'?

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, tensorflow

I want to install tensorflow with CPU support and I'm seeing this error:

```
C:\Users\brokk>python
Python 3.6.5 (v3.6.5:f59c0932b4, Mar 28 2018, 17:00:18) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tensorflow
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\brokk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 14, in swig_import_helper
return importlib.import_module(mname)
  File "C:\Users\brokk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 658, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 571, in module_from_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 922, in create_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
ImportError: DLL load failed: Eine DLL-Initialisierungsroutine ist fehlgeschlagen.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\brokk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-Packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\brokk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 17, in <module>
_pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\brokk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 16, in swig_import_helper
return importlib.import_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal')
  File "C:\Users\brokk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\brokk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
  File "C:\Users\brokk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Users\brokk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in <module>
raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\brokk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 14, in swig_import_helper
return importlib.import_module(mname)
  File "C:\Users\brokk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 658, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 571, in module_from_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 922, in create_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
ImportError: DLL load failed: Eine DLL-Initialisierungsroutine ist fehlgeschlagen.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\brokk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\brokk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 17, in <module>
_pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\brokk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 16, in swig_import_helper
return importlib.import_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal')
  File "C:\Users\brokk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.
```

I've tried:

- reinstalling several times under different conditions
- doublechecked the MSVCP140.DLL as suggested in other Questions
- tried out different versions of python
- getting the  cuDNN and  CUDA 8.0 although I don't need them for CPU use
- installed Microsoft visual studio 2015 community edition

But nothing has solved this, and I still get the `"ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'"` error.

Answer (score 0):

Can you just reinstall anaconda and then try to install tensorflow with pip install tensorflow.

Anaconda link : https://www.anaconda.com/download/

After installing these let me know if there are any issues.

Comment: the whole stack trace is to long for the comments' section but it said "ImportError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'" several times

Comment: it is exactly the same stack trace as before

Comment: Which version of tensorflow have you installed?

Answer (score 0):

I finally gave up and installed Linux on my PC and there it was working.